How to Prevent Visual Studio activating the OUTPUT window each time it is brought up
For some reason each I run / execute VSC it brings up the OUTPUT window. I must have accidentally enabled something in VSC to make this occur, but not sure what. Can someone let me know howt prevent this window from appearing.
You will not that is states that its preparing Synapse pyspark, but I don't need that.
Preparing synapse pyspark env...
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

